# The finitely generated-ness of ideals $I +rR$ and $I:r$ imply $I$ is a finitely generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$, and let $r ∈ R$. Show that if the ideals $I +rR$ and $I:r=\{s∈R:sr∈I\}$ are finitely generated, then $I$ is a finitely generated ideal.

Can anyone give some help or hints, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $(I,r)=(a_1+rx_1,\ldots,a_k+rx_k)$ and $(I:r)=(b_1,\ldots,b_s)$, with $a_i\in I$ and consider $a_1,\ldots,a_k,rb_1,\ldots,rb_s$.

*Spoiler*

> Note that if $x\in I$ then we can write $x=\sum r_ia_i+r \sum r_i x_i$. Then $\sum r_ix_i\in (I:r)$, say it equals $\sum s_ib_i$, and hence $x=\sum r_ia_i+\sum s_irb_i$.

Comment: can i ask why we can write write $x=\sum r_ia_i+r \sum r_i x_i$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user138017 Because $x\in I\subseteq (I,r)$. Note the sum is $\sum r_i(a_i+rx_i)$.

Comment: i am not sure it is ture that I⊆(I,r). if r is not in I, then I is not a subset of (I,r).

Comment: @user138017 You're forgetting $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: is it any sub-ideal of a finitely generated ideal is finitely generated? That means we don't need to prove anything?

Comment: @user138017 That's not true. The ring $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ (polynomials in infinitely many variables) is generated as an ideal (over itself) by $1$, but the ideal $(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: My point is that $Ir\subseteq I$ since $I$ is an ideal.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint.** $0\to r(I:r)\to I\to (I+rR)/rR\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of $R$-modules.

Comment: How do we see this above exact sequence. I can see the following exact sequence, $0\to (I:r)\to R\to (I+rR)/I\to 0$, which is not helpful in the above situation.